# IDictionary<T,K> : Using custom class as key

Tags: .net, generics, generic-collections

I was using `IDictionary<KeyClass, ValueClass>` in one of my projects. The `KeyClass` is very simple containing just two integers.

```
public class KeyClass
{
    public int ValueA{get;set;}
    public int ValueB{get;set;}
}
```

I was accessing values from dictionary like follows:

```
var k = new KeyClass(1, 1);
var v = myDictionary[k];
```

The dictionary for sure contained `KeyClass` key with `ValueA = 1` and `ValueB = 1` and simillarly many other keys. But I got exception:

```
The given key is not present in the dictionary.
```

I implemented `IComparable` in class `KeyClass` but it did not solve my problem. I googled and found this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dictionary_customkey.aspx) article. It describes following technique to use a class implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface. I defined it in my class:

```
public class KeyClass
{
    public int ValueA{get;set;}
    public int ValueB{get;set;}

    public class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyClass>
    {
        public bool Equals(KeyClass a, KeyClass b)
        {
            return a.ValueA == b.ValueA && a.ValueB == b.ValueB;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(KeyClass k)
        {
            return k.ValueA ^ k.ValueB;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have to declare `IDictionary<KeyClass, ValueClass>` as follows:

```
var d = new Dictionary<KeyClass, ValueClass>(new KeyClass.EqualityComparer());
```

Things worked fine afterwards.

My question is that I was using same class in save environment (.Net 4.0, Windows 7 desktop app) and `KeyClass` was working without `IEqualityComparet<T>` implementation in another project, but why it stopped working after I put the classes in this project?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to implement `IEqualityComparer<KeyClass>`. Rather, override the `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods in `KeyClass`.

```
public class KeyClass
{
    public int ValueA{get;set;}
    public int ValueB{get;set;}

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false.
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
        KeyClass p = obj as KeyClass;
        if ((System.Object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return a.ValueA == b.ValueA && a.ValueB == b.ValueB;
    }

    public bool Equals(KeyClass p)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false:
        if ((object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return this.ValueA == p.ValueA && this.ValueB == b.ValueB;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyClass k)
    {
        return k.ValueA ^ k.ValueB;
    }
}
```

You only need `IEqualityComparer<KeyClass>` if you're doing a custom comparison--something that's different from the default comparison. But since you control `KeyClass`, you can specify the default comparison in the class.

If you do it this way, then you don't have to supply a comparer when you create the dictionary. That is, you can write:

```
var d = new Dictionary<KeyClass, ValueClass>();
```

[See Guidelines for Equals() and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

The reason it didn't work before is probably because the default comparison for reference types is reference equality. So if you write:

```
var k = new KeyClass(1, 1);
var v = new ValueClass(..);
d.Add(k, v);

var k1 = new KeyClass(1, 1);
var v1 = d[k1];
```

You're going to get "key not found" because 'k' and 'k1' are not the same object. But if you wrote:

```
var v1 = d[k];
```

You'd find the value because `k` is the key that you stored in the dictionary.

Overriding `Equals` solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A class is a reference type - by default one reference is compared to another based on whether they point to the same instance of the class, not based on the values of its properties.

You'd be able to retrieve the item from the dictionary using the original instance you added the item with but not with some other instance that happens to have the same values for ValueA and ValueB.

If you want that behaviour you must either use a value type (a struct instead of a class), a custom comparer (as you have done) or you must override the Equals() and GetHashCode() methods of KeyClass.

Using a struct is probably the best option in this case but it's important to understand the implications of using them which you can read up on here:
[Struct (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4.aspx)